# Adding a filter increases visit count

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a dashboard for one of my clients, where their pages are all `mysite.com/[clientname]/page`.  I've added filters into each widget for `Path contains 'clientname'` however this is now showing a greater numebr of visits than my core dashboard.

Using Custom Advanced Segments elsewhere achieves what I want, but I can't see how to do this in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard filters are more like report filters on other reports and are different than custom segments.

The filters are applied on the resulting data while the segment is applied in the raw data prior to processing.

I recommend only filtering the dimension you are seeing on the widget. So a filter on page only make sense if you are showing pageview metrics or a list of top pages.